# Ionic sass duplicates in main.css

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I am building an ionic project. Here are the specs.

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : none
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
ios-deploy : 1.9.1
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
npm        : 3.10.10
```

Now to the issue. When SASS compiles I am getting triplets of everything.

```
.my-class{
}
.my-class{
}
.my-class{
}
```

Its making my stylesheets HUGE! Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Judson

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was importing my global sass file into other sass files which was not needed.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the issue. Please mark this as the accepted answer so we can close the issue :)